# swipe events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm using the mousewheel plugin for jQuery to run some animations on mouse scroll, and I'm looking for the easiest/cleanest way to simply add swipe gestures to the existing code for use on tablets.

What is a recommended plugin/library to accomplish this? I don't think I want to load the entire jquery mobile library just for this one section, so I'm looking for a small plugin similar to the mousewheel plugin if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swipe is not an event but rather combination of following:

```
1) touchstart
2) touchmove
3) touchend
```

you can build your algo  to decide if there is "swipe" and in which direction.

read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html for more info

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the entire jquery mobile, they have a pretty cool [**custom dowload builder**](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) where you can just select the component you want.

Comment: I just read on there that.. "the jQuery Mobile Download Builder is still in alpha, and as such should not be used on production websites."