# Binding swipe event with on()

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having some problems in binding the swipe(more specific, swipe left) event to a table row. i MUST use on() because my table rows are added later in the page. This is how i tried and it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Should i use other plugins? ive tryed different ones, same result...must be the event binding in the on().

```
    $("#tabel_comenzi").on("touchSwipeLeft", ".rand_comanda td" ,function(e){//de facut cu slide spre stanga
        var idComanda=$(this).parent().attr("record");
        var cantComanda=$(this).parent().children("td:nth-child(4)").text()-'0';
        var lungime= $(this).parent().children("td:nth-child(3)").text().length
        var pret = $(this).parent().children("td:nth-child(3)").text().substring(0,lungime-3);

        $.post("../template/masa/gestionare_comanda.php",{id:idComanda, cant:cantComanda-1});

        $(this).parent().children("td:nth-child(4)").text(cantComanda-1);
        $(this).parent().children("td:nth-child(5)").text(pret*(cantComanda-1)+"RON");

        if(cantComanda-1==0){
            $(this).parent().delay(1000).fadeOut(1000).remove();
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I've tried adding the swipe event directly to jquery on() function, still no good...Im using cj-swipe plugin...

Comment: Not trying to use jquery mobile.... I need to make it work with any other swipe function... for example i am trying to use cj-swipe.

Comment: You have to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522513/swipe-events-in-jquery and develop your own solution or use something else like http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries. Oh, sorry, let me search that cj-swipe plugin.